# Move a SQL Azure Server between subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I’m trying to move a SQL Azure Server that has 2 databases from one subscription to another. The databases’ sizes are 10G and 1G. I’m using the azure portal to do it and I’m getting the following error

There was an error moving resources.

> Resources '/subscriptions/f4b0ab63/resourceGroups/rg_asisa/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sqlasisatools' could not be moved. 
>   The tracking Id is xxx (Code: ResourceMoveFailed) Subscription 'f4b0ab63' does not have the server 'sqlasisatools'. (Code: SubscriptionDoesNotHaveServer)

Comment: The error seems to say , you may need to have logical server first

Comment: I have the server, in fact I'm trying to move it using the portal and the first step its to open the blade of the sql sever

Comment: Which doc are you following to do this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources

Answer (score 2):

I contacted engineers at SQL Azure team. In this case, they recommend you to open a support case in Azure.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Previously I had submit a ticket for migrate Azure SQL from one subscription to another, and from one sql server to another.

End up, I need to redeploy everything, because these 2 sql server are located in different AD.

Hope this info help you. :)